# Retrieve Indices while performing K-Means algorithm

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, k-means

I have a data frame of following form;

```
dict_new={'var1':[1,0,1,0,2],'var2':[1,1,0,2,0],'var3':[1,1,1,2,1]}
pd.DataFrame(dict_new,index=['word1','word2','word3','word4','word5'])
```

Please note that actual dataset is quite big, above example is for simplicity. Then I performed K-means algorithm in sickit-learn, and took 2 cluster centroids for simplicity.

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
num_clusters = 2
km = KMeans(n_clusters=num_clusters,verbose=1)
km.fit(dfnew.to_numpy())
```

Suppose the new cluster centroids are given by

```
centers=km.cluster_centers_
centers
array([[0.        , 1.5       , 1.5       ],
       [1.33333333, 0.33333333, 1.        ]])
```

The goal is to find two closest words for each cluster centroid, i.e. for each cluster center identify two closest words. I used the `distance_matrix` from `scipy` package, and got the output as a `2 x 5` matrix, corresponding to 2 centers and 5 words. Please see code below.

```
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix
distance_matrix(centers,np.asmatrix(dfnew.to_numpy()))
array([[1.22474487, 0.70710678, 1.87082869, 0.70710678, 2.54950976],
   [0.74535599, 1.49071198, 0.47140452, 2.3570226 , 0.74535599]])
```

But we don't see the word indices here. So I am not being able to identify the two closest words for each centroid. Can I kindly get help on how we can retrieve the indices(which was defined in the original data frame). Help is appreciated.

Comment: Show your full code.

Comment: I'm picky here but "the closest words" is not a straighforward concept and you have to define a metric to measure the distance between each word and the centroids. If you use the euclidian norm, I would suggest that you can either simply calculate the distance between all words and centroids if your dataset and number of centroids is not too big and performance is not an issue, or use something like ```scipy.spatial.distance``` if it is - here's some code using it in a similar case: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28207/finding-the-closest-point-to-a-list-of-points).

Comment: Agreed to our comment. Metric is not a big issue, `Euclidean` is fine. But my concern is how can I know which word is corresponding to a particular column in the distance matrix. Because the `distance` function gives just a matrix, as shown above in the edits, but we don't get any information regarding which words(i.e. indices) correspond to those entries in the matrix. Advice will be appreciated.

Comment: I added an answer using `distance_matrix` from SciPy! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that I understand what you want to do properly, here is a minimal working example on how to find the index of the words.

First, let's generate a similar reproducible environement

```
# import packages
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix

# set up the DataFrame
dict_new={'var1':[1,0,1,0,2],'var2':[1,1,0,2,0],'var3':[1,1,1,2,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_new,index= ['word1','word2','word3','word4','word5'])

# get the cluster centers
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit(np.array(df))
centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_
```

---

**If you only need to know the one closest word**

Now, if you wanted to use a distance matrix, you could do (instead):

```
def closest(df, centers):
     # define the distance matrix
     mat = distance_matrix(centers, np.asmatrix(df.to_numpy()))
     # get an ordered list of the closest word for each cluster centroid
     closest_words = [df.index[i] for i in np.argmin(mat, axis=1)]

     return closest_words

# example of it working for all centroids
print(closest(df, centers))
# > ['word3', 'word2']
```

---

**If you need to know the 2 closest words**

Now, if we want the two closest words:

```
def two_closest(df, centers):
     # define the distance matrix
     mat = distance_matrix(centers, np.asmatrix(df.to_numpy()))
     # get an ordered list of lists of the closest two words for each cluster centroid
     closest_two_words = [[df.index[i] for i in l] for l in np.argsort(mat, axis=1)[:,0:2]]
     
     return closest_two_words

# example of it working for all centroids
print(two_closest(df, centers))
# > [['word3', 'word5'], ['word2', 'word4']]
```

---

Please tell if this is not what you wanted to do or if my answer does not fit your needs! And don't forget to mark the question as answered if I solved your problem.

Comment: Appreciate your advice. I am trying to see if we can modify it to get two closest words for each centroid. thats my main requirement.

Comment: Your approach is more efficient. I figured it out but using a slower approach using the idea of `list`.appreciate your help.